# How to get Similar Keys in Javascript Object to a given word in o(1) time complexity

Tags: javascript, hashmap

- Please Note I am not looking for to do it in for loop... I know that solution already like in 10 different ways especially using Object.keys(myObject), then do a quick `regex` or `.search`.

Since I am working for over 15k properties in object so array system is not exactly what I am looking for. Any other solutions.

Is it possible to find similar keys with O(1) time complexity. For example:

```
const a = {
  warp1: 43,
  warp2: 87,
  warp.34: 19,
  warp_63: 82,
  warp_fundamental: 91,
  shop_41:9,
  warp.12:911,...
}
```

Let's say I want to extract all keys which begins with warp* and extract it in an array.

Solution which I am looking for is `['warp1','warp2', 'warp.34', 'warp_63','warp_fundamental', 'warp.12' ]`
Is it possible with javascript?

Comment: I could be wrong, but as it is, I find it hard to believe it is possible to do this with O(1) time complexity.

Comment: Solution as Array is fine. But let's say i did Object.keys(myObject). Now I have an array of length 15k. If I work with this length of array just to do a search is very time taking process.

Comment: @JoseNuno Well this is my fear myself. So, I thought of posting this in stack overflow. Working with 15-25k data as hashmap is truely blazing fast. But now i am asked to also show similar keys just like how I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, it's impossible to do better than `O(n^2)`, because you have to check each item, and, for each item, check each character of the search string (more precisely, `O(n*m)`, i.e. number of items x length of the search).

However, if you're applying the search repeatedly to the same set of data, you can spend n^2 cycles first to build a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and then perform subsequent searches in logarithmic time.

`O(1)` is only possible if you have a fixed set of search strings and precompute results for them all.

Comment: O(n^2) for 15k data not a good idea anyway.

Comment: @TrickOrTreat: it's `n*m` actually, number of items x length of search.

Comment: n is 15k... Not good idea. Hashmaps are good for search, searching key in even 25k data takes me less that 0.01ms itself, but this...

Comment: @TrickOrTreat Searching a key in a HashMap is O(1) in fact, but it seems that what you are trying to do would always require some iteration of some sort.

Comment: Searching is one task which I am accomplishing with O(1) only.
Above mentioned is another task which I am trying to accomplish, at least see any leads to it. Unfortunately no luck.